# Understanding the Log file

Tags: compiling, output

I'm getting some cryptic (for me) errors and warnings when I compile.  On the advice of darn near every internet resource I could find, I dug into the .log file.  The trouble is, I don't know how to interpret what I see.

I don't want to take up people's time so, where can I find a Reading LaTex .log Files for Beginners document?

Comment: I think this may be too broad a question, since many packages influence what is written out to the `.log` file. Moreover, some errors are cryptic in themselves, pointing to one thing that actually was not a problem in the first place. I think a good place to start is going through the TeX Book from Chapter **6 Running TeX** (p 22). There are some example of TeX output (which end up in the `.log` file) and how to interpret it. Perhaps redraft your question with a specific part of the log file in mind, in order to solicit more accurate responses.

Comment: See also Appendix C **Error Messages** of *A Guide to LaTeX*, 4ed.

Comment: I really, really appreciate your "don't do it for me, help me to learn how to do it"-take on the problem. However, in this case the actual problem example would be helpful to start the process.

Comment: [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) (and I guess many other LaTeX-editors as well) will help you to understand the log file with an integrated Messages/Log viewer. You can just click on each message and Texmaker will jump to the line in the .tex file where it thinks the error/warning came from.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here are some elements of a `.log` file:

- The `.log` file starts out by giving some information about the compiler that you are running. For example, running `latex` or `pdflatex` the output is

  ```
  This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (Web2C 2011)
  ```

  while running `xelatex` would output

  ```
  This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (Web2C 2011)
  ```
- Every file (including the document class `.cls` and style `.sty` files) that is loaded starts with an opening "`(`" and the file name. When the file has finished loading, a closing "`)`". All messages that happen during that file are written between those parenthesis. Sometimes this includes the file version or a short description of the file, as written by the package author).

  ```
  (./test.tex (./hello.tex This is a message from hello.tex) [1] )
  ```
- The page numbers are written in `[` `]` square brackets.
- LaTeX issues "bad box" warnings whenever you have something contained within a box (the general TeX layout structure) that does not fit within it. Here's a small working example

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
  Thisisaverylonglinethatdoesnotbreakproperlyattheendofthelineandcausesanoverfulhbox
  \end{document}
  ```

  that produces

  ```
  Overfull \hbox (46.52866pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 3--4
  []\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Thisisaverylonglinethatdoesnotbreakproperlyattheendofthelinea
  ndcausesanoverfulhbox 
   []
  ```

  in your `.log` file. This means that the contents of the box (in this case a box of width `\linewidth`) was exceeded by `46.52866pt` at lines 3-4 in your code. An actual output code segment is also visible, with the fonts loaded to typeset that "bad" part of your document (`OT1/cmr/m/n/10`). These "bad boxes" are tallied and given at the very end of your compile (although this does not form part of the actual `.log` file):

  ```
  LaTeX-Result: 0 Error(s), 0 Warning(s), 1 Bad Box(es), 1 Page(s)
  ```
- You may sometimes get warnings such as

  ```
  LaTeX Warning: Reference myref on page 1 undefined on input line 6.
  ```

  This means that you have used `\ref` or one of its relatives without having the appropriate `\label`. In this case, you will also get

  ```
  LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
  ```

  at the end of your `log` file.
- Similarly, if you define the same `\label` in multiple places, then you will  get

  ```
  LaTeX Warning: Label `mypage' multiply defined.
  ```

  which will lead to

  ```
  LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels.
  ```

  at the end of your `log` file.
- Sometimes fonts cannot be found. Either a font shape (for example slanted) or some requested font size is not available. Then you'll get a message like:

  ```
  LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/bx' undefined
  (Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 3.
  ```

  or

  ```
  LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <5.42497> not available
  (Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 72.
  ```

Many of the aforementioned information is obtained by an issue of `\typeout{<stuff>}` which outputs `<stuff>` to the terminal window (and subsequently makes its way into the `.log` file). Warnings and errors, also included in the `.log` file, arise from an issue of `\<cmd>Warning` or `\<cmd>Error` where `<cmd>` either refers to `Class` or `Package`.

To some extent it is possible to have control over the information output to the `.log` file by using the [`silence` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/silence). It provides a means to filter or activate warnings, errors or other messages from packages.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely covers many of the cryptic notes I was seeing.

Comment: Just a small addition: If you use `\documentclass[draft]{article}` your overfull boxes will be marked in black in your output, making it easier to find them.

Comment: Glad I found this as it addresses the particular situation I was trying to resolve.

Answer (score 8):

For errors and warnings see The LaTeX Companion, 2nd Edition, Appendix B: Tracing and Resolving Problems

Comment: Thank you!  My book budget is limited, so I was hoping for an online-resource.  Hmm...I wonder if the public library has any?

Comment: @HTG [The LaTeX Companion, 2nd Edition online free trial at safari](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/graphic-design/0201362996/firstchapter)