# Weird behaviour from graphicx - inserting PDF files

Tags: floats, positioning

So I created some graphs in Excel, saved them as PDFs and used the following code to import them to LaTeX:

```
\newpage
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{white1.pdf}
\caption{This figure shows the commulative oxygen production rate of white light in iteration number 1. The SEM bars show reading error from the pipette. }

\end{figure}

\newpage
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{green2.pdf}
\caption{This figure shows the commulative oxygen production rate of green light in iteration number 2. The SEM bars show reading error from the pipette. }

\end{figure}
\newpage
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{white3.pdf}
\caption{This figure shows the commulative oxygen production rate of green light in iteration number 3. The SEM bars show reading error from the pipette. }

\end{figure}


\newpage
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{green4.pdf}
\caption{This figure shows the commulative oxygen production rate of green light in iteration number 4. The SEM bars show reading error from the pipette. In this figure there is overlapping of SEM bars that show no significance difference }

\end{figure}

\newpage
\section{Discussion}
```

However the problem is that the new page at the very end (discussion) is not in order. It gets injected after the first figure.

So if the pages were numbered like this:

```
fig1, fig2, fig3, fig4, dis1
```

everytime I try to create the dis1 page by `\newpage` I get the following output:

```
fig1, dis1, fig2, fig3, fig4
```

Anyone know what's happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\clearpage` instead of `\newpage`. It will process all floats before creating a new page.

Answer (score 1):

This typically happens with floats that have a contents larger than the text block dimensions. Presumably, in your case, `green2.pdf` (the first "offender") is flushed to a page of floats and subsequently pushed until there is nothing left to typeset before it is finally printed. Use @Herbert's suggestion to flush (or process) any pending floats, or modify the size of the imported graphic so it will fit within the text block.

Note that a width of `0.9\textwidth` will fit the image within the text block width, but it - together with the caption - could still be larger than the text block height (`\textheight`).

Comment: okay. i am still learning (pretty new here) so I didn't really get anything you said but I guess with experience I'll know what you are talking about. thanks

Comment: Ask the questions - that's what this site is for! `:)` Floats are meant to float around in your document. You use the float specifiers `htbp` to say put the float `h`ere if possible, otherwise `t`op of the page, otherwise `b`ottom of the page, otherwise on a `p`age of floats. When all these fail (typically with an oversized graphic), further processing of floats is suspended until later in the document. Using `\clearpage` flushes this build-up. On a related note - is `green2.pdf` larger than the other images? Did LaTeX complain and give any wanrings?

Comment: I am not sure. I hit compile and i see a bunch of stuff at the bottom of the screen. never bothered reading if there was a warning. I'll find out and let you know.

Comment: That "stuff" is information about the compile processes, which makes its way into a `.log` file. If you're interested in finding out what this `.log` file is all about and how to interpret it, read [Understanding the Log file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32213/understanding-the-log-file).