# How to find the .cls file of the document that you are typesetting?

Tags: document-classes

I can't find the .cls file of the document that I want to typeset. The source code of the document is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,stdletter,sigleft]{newlfm}
\usepackage{charter}

\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000

\newsavebox{\Luiuc}
\sbox{\Luiuc}{%
    \parbox[b]{1.75in}{%



    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

Enclosed is my curriculum vitae (including a list of

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

And I want to remove the date that comes up here:

[image]

Comment: Please include source code directly in the side, [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). Also, please only ask one question per question. (Not 1. Where to find the .cls file and 2. How to remove the date (which you already asked in another place -> duplicate)). Finally, please try to tag a little more specifically. This question has nothing to do with the editor you're using (TeXworks), and neither with the compilation engine (`pdftex`).

Comment: Just take a look at the log file of your document.

Comment: It's usually not necessary to read the code of a class to use it. Probably you would be better with the documentation, which you should see if you run `texdoc newlfm` at the Command Prompt.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: Please make that into an answer.

Comment: The big question: _[Why](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal)_ do you want to finde the _source_ of the class you are using? You are _not_ supposed to change that.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers.

Answer (score 6):

As seen in the [Texlive Guide documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-660007.2.2), at the command line prompt type

`kpsewhich package-name.cls`, to locate the path of the `.cls`.

for more options refer the Texlive kpsewhich standalone path searching tools options

Answer (score 4):

You can see the source code of the document class in question without having to know where it is saved in your machine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset
{
    language=[LaTeX]TeX,
    breaklines=true,
}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{newlfm.cls}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you can duplicate the file as follows. Make sure you pass the option `-shell-escape` to the TeX compiler of your choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\filename{newlfm.cls}
\begin{document}
\newread\reader
\openin\reader=\filename
\newwrite\writer
\immediate\openout\writer=\filename
    \loop
        \readline\reader to \data
        \unless\ifeof\reader
            \immediate\write\writer{\data}
    \repeat
\immediate\closeout\writer
\closein\reader
\filename\ has been copied to your working directory.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you [check the logfile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32213/5763) of the compilation, TeX there tells you the complete path to all included files (which includes the '.cls' of your document class).