# Did the source code of The LaTeX Companion compile with no warnings and no bad-boxes?

Tags: warnings

Not only out of curiosity, but also to know the extent to which one should delegate the document arrangement to LaTeX! And how much is too much for "manual work"

Comment: Related [Do I have to care about bad boxes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50830/15717) and [Why/When should I pay attention to warnings?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109451/15717)

Comment: Frank has some comments about the amount of hand control over page breaking used in the endnotes to the book.